# ROR: Help for simple sum sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sum

I have a table that hold values for school_user_id and homework associated with each school_user as follows:

```
create_table "homework_students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "school_user_id", limit: 4, null: false
    t.integer  "homework_id",    limit: 4, null: false
    t.datetime "completed_on"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",
```

Each school_user is associated with an individual homework and homework has many school_users.

I am trying to print the total school_users connected to an individual piece of homework on my view.

In my controller:

```
@total = HomeworkStudent.where("SELECT homework_id FROM homework_students WHERE 'school_user_id = (?)'").sum(:school_user_id)
```

Models

```
homework
has_many :homework_students, :class_name => 'HomeworkStudent'

homework_students
belongs_to :homework, :class_name => 'Homework', :foreign_key => :homework_id
```

I don't think this is right in my syntax - it keeps printing 0.

Any ideas and also nicer ways one might do this?

EDIT

Got it with this.

```
@total = HomeworkStudent.find_by_sql("SELECT homework_id FROM homework_students WHERE school_user_id GROUP BY homework_id").count
```

Still would like to know if better way.

Comment: Sum? .. Or Count?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Hi! Sorry, count. I changed it but still returns 0. I think I have things back to front in my syntax...

Answer (score 2):

You do some mistakes:

1. the `where(...)` should not contain a `WHERE` statement and not a full query
2. your `WHERE` statement contains a placeholder which didn't fill up with data, `school_user_id = (?)`
3. your `WHERE` statement is wrapped into `'` which results in an interpretation as string in the DB.

Try this:

```
@total = HomeworkStudent.where(school_user_id: 123).count
# or
@total = HomeworkStudent.where("school_user_id = (?)", 123).count
```

Comment: Thanks, I made changes but it still returns 0. :( I think i'm close to it.

Comment: When I have problems like this I like to take it to the Rails Console `rails c` and see what the SQL looks like. It sounds like you're getting nothing back. If you take the `.count` off the end you'll probably see nothing is being returned. You can cut/paste the SQL into your SQL program of choice see what's up.

Comment: @Dan Thanks, nothing is being returned but the table is populated right - it's the query is the problem. Each homework has multiple school_users, i'm just looking to return the total for each homework.

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it with this: @total = HomeworkStudent.find_by_sql("SELECT homework_id FROM homework_students WHERE school_user_id GROUP BY homework_id").count   Still be interested to know if there is a better way though...

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 you can use only key value with `where`.

Meanwhile you dose not need to write full `sql` query code into `where`.

For count you use simple count method.

For Example,

```
@users = User.where(age: 20).count
```